# Photoshop CC colour picker is wrong

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

[image]

My colour picker is set to point sample, so it is not mixing colours, I am also on the correct layer.
Does anyone know whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Is sample all layers on? If not the layer might have a layer mode that alters the color or a adjustment on top. If sample all layers isn't on then Photoshop samples the ACTUAL color on the layer not what it looks after blending and adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/color-picker-in-photoshop-is-wrong) may be a solution:

> To fix this, when the eye dropper is selected, change the sample size at the top to Point Sample

If thats no fix, here is another [ressource](http://www.photography-forums.com/threads/color-picker-freezes-photoshop-cs.71308/):

> A lot of Photoshop problems can be fixed by dumping the preferences
>   file: While launching Photoshop, Hold down Alt+Ctrl+shift on the PC or
>   Cmd+Option+Shift on the mac. When asked to reset the preferences say
>   yes. Before you do this, save your custom Patterns, actions, styles,
>   brushes, gradients, shapes and color pallettes. These will also be
>   reset. Tip: You can create an action to do this, so you have a one
>   click backup! (Don't forget to save the backup action first)

Answer (score 1):

The layer you are painting on might be on different blending mode. Check if its on normal mode. If not then change it to normal.    Also make sure opacity is 100%.